# How do I secure my Jupyter notebook with SSL from my Azure Data Science Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, ssl, jupyter-notebook, azure-dsvm

What is an effective procedure I can follow to secure my Jupyter Notebook?

I created an Azure Data Science machine as per the instructions here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/dsvm-ubuntu-intro),

and my Jupyter notebook is being accessed at https://public-ip:8000 (this is the default port that was automatically configured when the VM was created).

However, when I access it, it states that the connection is not secure.

It seems like ssl gives certificates for port 8888, and Let's Encrypt in general gives certificates for port 80. Any advice on how I can get secure connection for my Azure Data Science VM?

Let me know if my question is vague / needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html

I believe Let's Encrypt does not allow signing DNS names from Azure. But there are is an alternate way given in the article.